# Activity -> Boton "atras" que no reinicie mi app

Tags: android, kotlin

Lo que estoy buscando es que cuando presiono "atras" y no hay mas elementos en el stack se va a segundo plano al volver necesito que no se reinicia la actividad,

intente con

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
//        if (getCurrentVisibleFragment().toString().contains("HomeFragment")) {
//            moveTaskToBack(false)
//        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
//        }

    }
```

Pero no siempre funciona,

Vi que se puede guardar "el estado" para que el oncreate lo levante desde el bundle,

Pero tengo varias tareas en AsyncTask que se reinician, y no me gustaria que eso sucediera

No hay una forma de obligar a Android que no cierre mi acitivdad?,

Comment: Mira si esto te funciona https://stackoverflow.com/a/23752772/15298643

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando mandas a segundo plano tu app, el que se evite que se reinicie cuando regresas de segundo plano depende del sistema operativo, es decir, si el sistema operativo detecta que abres otras apps y estas requieren memoria, se puede provocar la eliminaciòn del proceso de tu app, por lo tanto, al regresar a la app que mandaste a segundo plano esta se reiniciarà.

No hay algo que se pueda realizar de parte del programador, depende del sistema operativo.

Comment: gracias estimado, veo que tendre que re hacer la logica, para que mis asyn task no se mueran en el background y aparte manejar las actividades

Comment: Hola Bruno para esto " para que mis async task no se mueran en el background", puedes usar un Service.

Answer (score 1):

Actividad es considerada tu app para evitar eso, en vez de cambiar de actividad usa los FrameLayout.
Lo único que tendrás que hacer es cargar el layout anterior en vez de volver.
T'he dejo un link de tutorial de como se usan:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WIBAT1g4jAQ